# Yahoo YQL Query feed reader not working

Tags: rss, feed, yql, yahoo-api, rss-reader

I have been using the yahoo yql service for reading rss feeds from websites, but today the rest url returned error

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20title%20from%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Frss.news.yahoo.com%2Frss%2Ftopstories%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=
```

**Result :**

```
{"query":{"count":0,"created":"2017-08-29T03:09:44Z","lang":"en-US","diagnostics":{"publiclyCallable":"true","url":{"execution-start-time":"1","execution-stop-time":"3","execution-time":"2","http-status-code":"400","http-status-message":"Bad Request","content":"http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/topstories"},"user-time":"3","service-time":"2","build-version":"2.0.164"},"results":null}}
```

Did they stop the service or any change needed to get it worked?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue. If you keep calling it, it eventually works. I put a workaround in to wait a second and try again for now. Hope you get an answer soon!